# Unable to find fonts after installing TexLive full on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu, linux

I've installed the full TeX Live on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04, using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install texlive-full
```

After installation, I am able to run LaTeX, PdfLaTeX, etc., but compilation fails whenever I try to specify a font.

Example: `test1.tex` contains

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgbonum}

\begin{document}
Hello world \LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Compiling it produces the following output:

```
$ pdflatex test1
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tex-gyre/tgbonum.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
No file test1.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ot1qbk.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdf
tex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test1.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+420/600 --dpi 420 rm-qbkr
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for rm-qbkr.
mktexpk: perhaps rm-qbkr is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rm-qbkr): Font rm-qbkr at 420 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Help fixing the installation will be appreciated!

Comment: Odd. Does `sudo texhash`, `sudo updmap-sys` fix this?

Comment: @Davislor, I get the same error even after running the commands you suggested.

Comment: It's working now after I purged the entire texlive installation and installed again. Not sure what went wrong the first time.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. It was a fine question to ask, but I’m going to vote to close it because the problem cannot be reproduced.